# What is the 10 in sqlite3 datatype varchar(10)?

Tags: sql, sqlite

If I create a table in `sqlite3` like:

```
create table sodapops (name text, description varchar(10));
```

What does the number 10 in `varchar` do? How would it be any different than 255 or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

In any other database, it would specify the maximum length of the field.

However, SQLite ignores it.  All strings are simply of text type and can be of any length.

As explained in the [documentation](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> Note that numeric arguments in parentheses that following the type
>   name (ex: "VARCHAR(255)") are ignored by SQLite - SQLite does not
>   impose any length restrictions (other than the large global
>   SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH limit) on the length of strings, BLOBs or numeric
>   values.

Comment: So it doesn't do anything? Does the number specification have some sort of a title that I can look up?